# Need Guidance for mobile number validation

Tags: java, regex

The Task it to check the input number is valid if it starts with only 7/8/9 and contains 10 digits.
Here is the code.
Correct me. I know I'm wrong.

```java
public boolean validateMobileNumber(long number) throws Exception {

    String num = Long.toString(number);

    String regex = "@\"^[7-9]{10}$";
    if (num.equals(regex))
        return true;
    else
        throw new Exception("Invalid Number");
}
```

Comment: "7/8/9" may be misunderstood. If you mean "7", 8 or 9" you should say that. Also, please clarify if the digits at the beginning of the string can be followed by other characters.

Comment: Your regex will fail if *any* digit among the 10 is other than a `7`, `8` or `9`. Is that your intent?

Comment: no!! it should start with 7 or 8 or 9 and should contain 10 digits in total

Comment: Then you want `^[7-9]\d{9}$`.

Comment: I tried this now but still, I get an exception

Comment: `String regex = "@[789]{9}$";` try it like this.

Comment: and also if I convert the Long number int String type and use it compare with regex, is that a correct way to validate.

Comment: You must use `String#matches()`, not `equals`

Comment: I don't know Java, but @SwissCodeMen's comment suggests you need to write `String regex = "@[7-9]\d{9}$";`

Comment: could you tell me how to use stringMatches()

Comment: thanks, gentlemen for your kind help.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you use `equals` to check the match of your regex. You will use [matches](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String))

```java
String num = "7123456789";
String regex = "^[7-9]\\d{9}$";

System.out.println(num.matches(regex));
```

Comment: Got it thibsc thanks mate